# Temperature rising for inductors

Tags: inductor, temperature

I have an U type inductor. I'd like to calculate temperature rising on the inductor. I found a formula but the result was approximatly 350-550 celcius, I think that is not possible.

Here my formula:

$$
T_r = 450(\Psi)^{0.826}
$$

$$
\Psi = \frac{P_{totalLOSS}}{A_t} 
$$ watt/cm2

At--> Total surface area of the magnetic core.

my values:

PtotalLOSS -->4.3846 Watt

At --> 4.7 or 5.6 cm2

Comment: You should explain where the formulas came from and better still, provide a hyperlink to a website that explains them. Do you think that a resistor dissipating 4.3846 watts would rise in temperature by 350-550 degC? Think about it.

Comment: Yes, that is not possible. I used [link](http://ebook.pldworld.com/_eBook/-Power%20Electronics-/TRANSFORMER%20and%20INDUCTOR%20DESIGN%20HANDBOOK%203rd%20Edition,%20Revised%20and%20Expanded/ourdev_725050HHOGA4.pdf) these resource. Go to page 309 by page counter. @Andyaka

Comment: OK, so the approximate outer dimensions of your core are significantly less than 9.7 mm x 9.7 mm x 9.7 mm (if it were a cube)?

Comment: I think you need to find a better document that fully explains what \$A_T\$ is. It doesn't appear to be shown in that massive document.

Comment: [Try this](http://w5jgv.com/hv-ps1/pdf/design_of_magnetic_components.pdf) for a better example of surface area. I think you have grossly miscalculated it.

Comment: [Here my U type inductor](https://www.ferroxcube.com/upload/media/product/file/Pr_ds/U10_8_3.pdf) Actually At is explained in the document but it is too large and to fınd is little bit hard.

Comment: That small core with that dissipation is going to get very warm for sure. Please show how you calculated surface area.

Comment: 350 'C sounds right for that size and P

Comment: $$ A_{t} = 2*E*(A-B)/2  + 2*( 2*D*(A-B) + B*(D-C) ) + 2*D*E + 2*C*E + B*E + A*E $$ I formulazed it. I calculated all surface area of the magnetic core. @Andyaka

Comment: Well your formula would be better in your question and with a picture of those dimensions extracted from the data sheet but, IMHO, it's just too small for that power dissipation.

Comment: @Andyaka you and Tony stewart said it is normal for this size cube and I changed the core with has bigger size one. I guess I have to change.